# Apps refuse to launch

Tags: software-center, snap, downloads

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 via the iso file downloaded directly from the ubuntu site. I had it initially as a dual boot, or multi boot as I included the previous iteration of ubuntu included(16.04LTS). Since the GNU GRUB menu has been erased, forcing me to use windows, I ultimately reinserted the usb drive containing the ubuntu system. I now use Ubuntu permanently. While I appreciate the intricacies and new features, however,some software and apps I've downloaded refuse to launch. Udemy, soloLearn, and more continue to stall and ultimately don't launch at all. They're listed under the applications so I'm curious as to why they refuse to execute, [The image attached is of my terminal, showing both responses when trying to launch udemy and sololearn(which it doesn't even recognize)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyG7R.png)although brackets now works. But as for the two aforementioned, nada. I've tried all routes of execution; double click, right click -->new window, and via the terminal. Does someone out there have any experience that could point the culprit and a possible solution?

Comment: The question lacks sufficient detail to be answerable as currently written. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418138/edit) above: Pick one application for an example, and explain clearly how you installed it (better yet, show us terminal output of the download and install if possible). Then try opening one way, and check your logs to see the error messages resulting from the failure. Show us those errors. Rinse and repeat for each way you try to open that application. The more detail you take the time to share, the faster and better you will get a solution.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

The packages you are trying to install are not available via apt, but they are on snap.

To install sololearn, enter the command

```
sudo snap install sololearn
```

To install udemy,

```
sudo snap install udemy
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Mr. Panigrahi. I appreciate the input in how to install them properly, yet the main issue persists. They won't launch. I just reinstalled them both, and they're along my side panel under favorites, but won't execute..
I tried using the terminal just typing sololearn,,,and then udemy. Do they require additional packages in order to work properly?

Comment: any additional packages should've been installed along with the package when you installed it... what errors are you getting? by the way, you should send a reply to the answer rather than make another one since that confuses things a little bit.

Comment: My apologies, It's been a while since I've even been around a legitimate computer. Honestly, it returns no error message. I type in either sololearn or udemy, and it returns nothing -as if it were actually executing. Both were installed via the terminal using sudo snap as prefix, so they're on here. Just refuse to open.